# How to select list box items that are in a list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box which is being populated by various truck features.
`featureListBox.ItemsSource = DAO.GetAllFeatures()`

I also have a TruckWithModel class which has an attribute that has a list of features that a specific truck has.
`TruckWithModel m = DAO.SearchByRego(regoComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Using the following code I am trying to select the features within the listbox.

```
for(int i = m.Features.Count -1; i>=0; --i)
                {
                    featureListBox.SelectedItems = m.Features[i];
                }
```

However, none are being selected as this property is read-only (.selecteditems).

How do I go about selecting the feature within the list box that match the features in the list?

**UPDATE:**

So I've managed to loop through the features list but however only ONE is being highlighted within the listbox.

```
for (int i = m.Features.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                {
                   featureListBox.SelectedValue = m.Features[i];
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `m.Features[i]` returns a string, I think you can do:

```
for (int i = m.Features.Count -1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   featureListBox.SelectedItems.Add(m.Features[i]);
}
```

On a side note, not sure why you are iterating in reverse, probably could just use a `foreach`.

Comment: theres no setselected function available nor findstring, I'm using entityframework if that helps and yes it is a list of strings

Comment: @BaldeepSahdra: Sorry about that. I updated the code for `wpf`.

Comment: You must also make sure that `featureListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;`.